# Inconsistent output of Dropdown Menu on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a very simple dropdown menu for selecting bank names.
Here is the code:

```
<select id = "bankoption">
<option value="bank1">bank1</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank4">bank4</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank27">bank27</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank22">bank22</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank19">bank19</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank21">bank21</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank15">bank15</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank23">bank23</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank18">bank18</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank26">bank26</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank10">bank10</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank17">bank17</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank20">bank20</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank16">bank16</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank9">bank9</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank11">bank11</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank13">bank13</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank3">bank3</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank7">bank7</option>
<option style = "display:none" value ="bank25">bank25</option>
<option value ="bank5">bank5</option>
<option value ="bank28">bank28</option>
</select>
```

According to above code **bank1, bank5** and **bank28** should be seen in the dropdown and not others. Surprisingly while firefox renders as expected the chrome only shows **bank1** option.

Here are the images attached.

[image]

[image]

Why the browsers are rendering them differently ? If I am doing the things in wrong way then what's the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

All of the expected values are showing up in the dropdown box. However in chrome, all of the hidden values are factored into the length of the list. If you click on the tiny down arrow, you can scroll to the other options. Another thing to note, I can select the hidden values by hitting the up and down arrows while the box is the focus. This is probably something that you do not want.

Comment: But why is this inconsistency across browsers. Is it a bug that we should report to chrome?

Comment: I wouldn't really call it a bug. All the browsers render web pages (slightly) differently. That's why it's a really good thing that you are testing in all the different browsers.